# post.populate(...).populate is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

```js
const Post = require('../models/post');
const Subreddit = require('../models/subreddit');
const User = require('../models/user');
const postTypeValidator = require('../utils/postTypeValidator');
const { cloudinary, UPLOAD_PRESET } = require('../utils/config');
const paginateResults = require('../utils/paginateResults');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const page = Number(req.query.page);
  const limit = Number(req.query.limit);
  const sortBy = req.query.sortby;

  let sortQuery;
  switch (sortBy) {
    case 'new':
      sortQuery = { createdAt: -1 };
      break;
    case 'top':
      sortQuery = { pointsCount: -1 };
      break;
    case 'best':
      sortQuery = { voteRatio: -1 };
      break;
    case 'hot':
      sortQuery = { hotAlgo: -1 };
      break;
    case 'controversial':
      sortQuery = { controversialAlgo: -1 };
      break;
    case 'old':
      sortQuery = { createdAt: 1 };
      break;
    default:
      sortQuery = {};
  }

  const postsCount = await Post.countDocuments();
  const paginated = paginateResults(page, limit, postsCount);
  const allPosts = await Post.find({})
    .sort(sortQuery)
    .select('-comments')
    .limit(limit)
    .skip(paginated.startIndex)
    .populate('author', 'username')
    .populate('subreddit', 'subredditName');

  const paginatedPosts = {
    previous: paginated.results.previous,
    results: allPosts,
    next: paginated.results.next,
  };

  res.status(200).json(paginatedPosts);
};

const getSubscribedPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const page = Number(req.query.page);
  const limit = Number(req.query.limit);

  const user = await User.findById(req.user);
  if (!user) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send({ message: 'User does not exist in database.' });
  }

  const subscribedSubs = await Subreddit.find({
    _id: { $in: user.subscribedSubs },
  });

  const postsCount = subscribedSubs
    .map((s) => s.posts.length)
    .reduce((sum, s) => s + sum, 0);

  const paginated = paginateResults(page, limit, postsCount);
  const subscribedPosts = await Post.find({
    subreddit: { $in: user.subscribedSubs },
  })
    .sort({ hotAlgo: -1 })
    .select('-comments')
    .limit(limit)
    .skip(paginated.startIndex)
    .populate('author', 'username')
    .populate('subreddit', 'subredditName');

  const paginatedPosts = {
    previous: paginated.results.previous,
    results: subscribedPosts,
    next: paginated.results.next,
  };

  res.status(200).json(paginatedPosts);
};

const getSearchedPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const page = Number(req.query.page);
  const limit = Number(req.query.limit);
  const query = req.query.query;

  const findQuery = {
    $or: [
      {
        title: {
          $regex: query,
          $options: 'i',
        },
      },
      {
        textSubmission: {
          $regex: query,
          $options: 'i',
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  const postsCount = await Post.find(findQuery).countDocuments();
  const paginated = paginateResults(page, limit, postsCount);
  const searchedPosts = await Post.find(findQuery)
    .sort({ hotAlgo: -1 })
    .select('-comments')
    .limit(limit)
    .skip(paginated.startIndex)
    .populate('author', 'username')
    .populate('subreddit', 'subredditName');

  const paginatedPosts = {
    previous: paginated.results.previous,
    results: searchedPosts,
    next: paginated.results.next,
  };

  res.status(200).json(paginatedPosts);
};

const getPostAndComments = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  const post = await Post.findById(id);
  if (!post) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send({ message: `Post with ID: '${id}' does not exist in database.` });
  }

  const populatedPost = await post
    .populate('author', 'username')
    .execPopulate();

  res.status(200).json(populatedPost);
};

const createNewPost = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    title,
    subreddit,
    postType,
    textSubmission,
    linkSubmission,
    imageSubmission,
  } = req.body;

  const validatedFields = postTypeValidator(
    postType,
    textSubmission,
    linkSubmission,
    imageSubmission
  );

  const author = await User.findById(req.user);
  const targetSubreddit = await Subreddit.findById(subreddit);

  if (!author) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send({ message: 'User does not exist in database.' });
  }

  if (!targetSubreddit) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      message: `Subreddit with ID: '${subreddit}' does not exist in database.`,
    });
  }

  const newPost = new Post({
    title,
    subreddit,
    author: author._id,
    upvotedBy: [author._id],
    pointsCount: 1,
    ...validatedFields,
  });

  if (postType === 'Image') {
    const uploadedImage = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
      imageSubmission,
      {
        upload_preset: UPLOAD_PRESET,
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error) return res.status(401).send({ message: error.message });
      }
    );

    newPost.imageSubmission = {
      imageLink: uploadedImage.url,
      imageId: uploadedImage.public_id,
    };
  }

  const savedPost = await newPost.save();

  targetSubreddit.posts = targetSubreddit.posts.concat(savedPost._id);
  await targetSubreddit.save();

  author.posts = author.posts.concat(savedPost._id);
  author.karmaPoints.postKarma++;
  await author.save();

  /* const populatedPost = savedPost;
  populatedPost.populate("author","username");
  populatedPost.populate("subreddit","subredditName");
    populatedPost.execPopulate(); */

  // res.status(201).json(populatedPost); //
};

const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  const { textSubmission, linkSubmission, imageSubmission } = req.body;

  const post = await Post.findById(id);
  const author = await User.findById(req.user);

  if (!post) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      message: `Post with ID: ${id} does not exist in database.`,
    });
  }

  if (!author) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send({ message: 'User does not exist in database.' });
  }

  if (post.author.toString() !== author._id.toString()) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Access is denied.' });
  }

  const validatedFields = postTypeValidator(
    post.postType,
    textSubmission,
    linkSubmission,
    imageSubmission
  );

  switch (post.postType) {
    case 'Text':
      post.textSubmission = validatedFields.textSubmission;
      break;

    case 'Link':
      post.linkSubmission = validatedFields.linkSubmission;
      break;

    case 'Image': {
      const uploadedImage = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
        imageSubmission,
        {
          upload_preset: UPLOAD_PRESET,
        },
        (error) => {
          if (error) return res.status(401).send({ message: error.message });
        }
      );

      post.imageSubmission = {
        imageLink: uploadedImage.url,
        imageId: uploadedImage.public_id,
      };
      break;
    }

    default:
      return res.status(403).send({ message: 'Invalid post type.' });
  }

  post.updatedAt = Date.now();

  const savedPost = await post.save();
  const populatedPost = await savedPost
    .populate('author', 'username')
    .populate('subreddit', 'subredditName')
    .populate('comments.commentedBy', 'username')
    .populate('comments.replies.repliedBy', 'username')
    .execPopulate();

  res.status(202).json(populatedPost);
};

const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  const post = await Post.findById(id);
  const author = await User.findById(req.user);

  if (!post) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      message: `Post with ID: ${id} does not exist in database.`,
    });
  }

  if (!author) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send({ message: 'User does not exist in database.' });
  }

  if (post.author.toString() !== author._id.toString()) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Access is denied.' });
  }

  const subreddit = await Subreddit.findById(post.subreddit);

  if (!subreddit) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      message: `Subreddit with ID: '${subreddit._id}'  does not exist in database.`,
    });
  }

  await Post.findByIdAndDelete(id);

  subreddit.posts = subreddit.posts.filter((p) => p.toString() !== id);
  await subreddit.save();

  author.posts = author.posts.filter((p) => p.toString() !== id);
  await author.save();

  res.status(204).end();
};

module.exports = {
  getPosts,
  getSubscribedPosts,
  getSearchedPosts,
  getPostAndComments,
  createNewPost,
  updatePost,
  deletePost,
};
```

I keep getting this error message when running the program:

TypeError: post.populate(...).execPopulate is not a function
at getPostAndComments (C:\Users\64bit\OneDrive\Documents\schoolreddit\server\controllers\post.js:149:6)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
post.populate(...).execPopulate is not a function
TypeError: post.populate(...).execPopulate is not a function
at getPostAndComments (C:\Users\64bit\OneDrive\Documents\schoolreddit\server\controllers\post.js:149:6)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Anyone know why I keep recieving this error message? I have been trying to resolve this for a few hours now, and I have no clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`.execPopulate()` [was removed in Mongoose v6](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-execpopulate), the correct syntax is:

```
const populatedPost = await post.populate('author', 'username');
```